# Test Actions on Google app on Raspberry Pi running Google Assistant SDK

Tags: raspberry-pi, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai

I created an Actions on Google app which I am currently testing. I was able to test it on my Pixel, but when I tried to launch the app on my Raspberry Pi running the Google Assistant SDK it responded by saying "(name of app) isn't supported on this device". Is there any way I can run the app on my Pi?

EDIT: Here is a picture of the surface capabilities.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the hotword or pushtotalk sample?

Comment: I am using the hotword sample.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of the "Surface Capabilities" section of your app configuration?

Comment: Sure, I added the picture.

Comment: We're tracking this bug on GitHub: https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/147